# Multiple Tables vs Indexed Rows

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, schema

I have a question that was brought up in a recent discussion with a co-worker.

Let's assume that you have a single table with 100,000,000 rows, and you each of those rows has an indexed column (varchar). There are 1000 unique values for this column, therefore each value has 100,000 rows related to it. I want to find all of the rows that are related to the one of the unique values (I will supply said value), but with some additional filtering logic as well (not important).

Would it be faster, slower, or just as fast to store 100,000 rows in 1000 different tables, and search *only* the table I need, or use the method listed above?

Assume all of the tables would have the same schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaching just the table you need will be faster.  It's like asking is it faster to search for ChapterX of a book, or just be given a book that is only ChapterX.

This is, however, mis-leading.  As how will you determine which table to query?  1000 IF statements, or a binary tree of IF statements so as to get there in 10 hops?  No matter what you write, I would NOT expect any of them to be faster than using the Index of the unified table.

Not to mention the clutter of 1000 tables.

There is an argument (and a time & place) for partitioning data, but this is a very poor example.

Comment: +1 In addition, the query optimizer **really** dislikes queries with large numbers of tables.

Comment: Also, if you have 100,000 repeats of the _exact same value_, you may consider pulling it out to a seperate table, and creating a (integer identity) foreign key reference to it.  The added cost of the additional table is most likely justified in having to process **far** fewer string comparisons; the garuanteed data integrity is a nice side effect.  (I was assuming the filtering was on the string... but are int comparisons a lot better regardless?)

Comment: @X-Zero : With 1000 distinct values the performance benefit of integer comparisons may be outwieghed by the associated need for a join.  That said, it's still (imo) best practice to avoid strings as identifiers where possible.

Comment: @Dems - #headdesk# You're right, I was thinking the index would still have to manually compare every row, but it can just get the (effectively sequential) list from the index.  But yeah, there's (usually) no reason to use strings as (in-database) identifiers.

Comment: @Dems, so would you consider the difference of the two techniques (in terms of speed) negligible, even if you knew what table to query?

Comment: @Xixonia - For 1000 unique indexed values, yes - the difference may be so small that you might not ever be able to measure a statistically reliable difference.

Comment: There's another aspect to this that hasn't been mentioned: B-Tree indexes are more efficient when shallower and smaller, so even if you don't partition into 1000 tables but instead say 10 or 50 tables that each contain a subset of the data, you'll still gain. It's not just index cost either; when data is clustered into multiple smaller tables there's a greater chance that you'll find more matching rows on the same heap pages.